# Run time error with twisted and cx_freeze

Tags: python, twisted, cx-freeze

I am currently trying to freeze some python code using twisted with cx_freeze.

I have this in my python file Main.py :

```
print('Start')
import twisted.internet
input('End')
```

and this in setup.py file :

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
includes = ["twisted.internet", "twisted.internet.protocol", "pkg_resources"]
excludes = []
packages = []
namespace_packages = ["zope"]
build_exe_options = {"packages": packages, "excludes": excludes, "includes": includes,      "namespace_packages": namespace_packages, "append_script_to_exe":True}
base = None
#if sys.platform == "win32":
#    base = "Win32GUI"
setup(  name = "xxx",
    version = "1.0",
    author = "xxx",
    author_email = "xxx",
    description = "xxx",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("Main.py", base=base, icon = None)])
```

I keep getting a run time error R6034 when I run my compiled program. Someone knows why ?

Comment: I just figured out that the line causing the error in the file twisted/__init.py__ is : from zope import interface

Comment: it comes from this line in the end : from _zope_interface_coptimizations import SpecificationBase

Comment: Please paste the complete error.  I can't say for sure, but it sounds like a problem with the C compiler on your system; specifically, that it doesn't match the one that Python was compiled with.  Please be extremely precise about what compiler you're using, how you installed everything, your build options for Python, and so on.

Comment: If it works correctly before freezing it, there's probably a file missing from the freeze process. But as @Glyph says, please do show the full error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I used a workaround. I figured out that the file zope.interface._zope_interface_coptimizations was the root of the issue (it fails to load) so I excluded it in my setup.py file :

```
excludes = ["zope.interface._zope_interface_coptimizations"]
```

It now works well but the initial problem is not solved and I fear I would need this package at some point.